# Firefox cannot start up on Archlinux any more

Tags: firefox, archlinux

It was working fine before. But today the following ways of turning on firefox all failed.

```
$ firefox
$ firefox --start-debugger-server
$ firefox --safe-mode
 addons.xpi WARN    Expected add-on followonsearch@mozilla.com is missing from the system add-on location.
```

firefox processes were shown in the following command

$ ps aux | grep firefox

I did `killall firefox` in between each attempt.

Firefox version is : 54.0.1

Comment: By any chance, do you have a mix of 32 and 64 bit packages installed on your system? I had very similar problem and uninstalling all 32bit packages on my machine solved it.

Comment: No, the same package was working just fine, but now it is not working. I actually suspect that maybe something like firewall or some security mechanism is blocking the complete startup. 

Is that possible the executalbe is infected? I can see after starting firefox, there are too processes spawn, but in sleep mode and doing nothing in the background. 

Interestingly, the parent firefox takes 0.5 - 8% CPU and 150 M resident memory, just as normal, however, there is no X11 UI shown up.